# MYSQL вложенный запрос с вычисляемыми полями

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос, phpmyadmin, таблицы

[image: схема]

На пикче представлена часть схемы бд. 
Задача: имеется id некоего аккаунта из таблицы accounts. В таблицах sections\lessons представлены видеоуроки, разделенные по секциям. В каждой секции разное кол-во уроков. В таблице progress фиксируется проверка прохождения видеоуроков.

Требуется вывести: кол-во уроков, пройденных пользователем (поле checked таблицы progress), сгруппированные по секциям (соотв. вывести id секции и поле sections.alias), общее кол-во уроков в секции и вычисляемое поле passed (проверка на равенства кол-во пройденных и общего кол-ва уроков в секции).

Пример заполнения таблицы progress:
[image: progress]

Как решил:

```
SELECT section_id,
    alias, 
    count_progress, 
    count_lessons, (count_progress = count_lessons) as passed 
FROM (SELECT l.section_id section_id,
        lower(s.alias) alias,
        count(*) as count_progress,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM lessons 
         WHERE section_id = l.section_id) count_lessons 
         FROM progress p 
         JOIN lessons l ON p.lesson_id = l.id 
         JOIN sections s ON l.section_id = s.id 
         WHERE p.account_id = 5 AND p.checked = 1
         GROUP BY s.id) as mytable
```

Результат выполнения запроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, если подставить в этот запрос аккаунт с id = 3, то запрос не выведет ничего.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуется, чтобы, даже если в таблице progress отсутствуют записи с checked = 1, выводились данные о секции\кол-ве уроков и т.д.

Ожидаемый результат запроса с account _id = 3:

**section_id | alias | count_progress | count_lessons | passed**

1 | intro | 0 | 3 | 0

Comment: не совсем понимаю, какие секции/уроки нужно выводить, если в таблице progress нет данных об этом пользователе? или нужно вывести все данные из таблицы sections/lessons?

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis как же нету, вот конкретно в этом случае пользователь с account_id = 3 (таблица progress, в примере заполнения), там 2 записи, в которых checked равны NULL. Раз записи в этой таблице созданы, значит он его начал проходить, просто еще не проверены уроки(checked). И надо считать пройденные уроки, т.е. в данном случае, count_progress должен выдать 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поправил Ваш запрос:

```
SELECT section_id,
alias, 
count_progress, 
count_lessons, (count_progress = count_lessons) as passed 
FROM (SELECT l.section_id section_id,
    lower(s.alias) alias,
    sum (case when cheked=1 then 1 else 0 end) as count_progress,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM lessons 
     WHERE section_id = l.section_id) count_lessons 
     FROM progress p 
     JOIN lessons l ON p.lesson_id = l.id 
     JOIN sections s ON l.section_id = s.id 
     WHERE p.account_id = 5
     GROUP BY s.id) as mytable
```

Comment: только между sum и скобкой пробела не должно быть, а то ошибку дает) Спасибо, Денис.

Comment: если ответ Вам подошел - поставьте галочку вверх)